# Printer is over extruding for the first few layers

Tags: extrusion, creality-cr-10

I'm facing a strange issue where my printer is over-extruding only for the first 6-8 layers (layer height of 0.2 mm).

All the layers above that have no such issue, which, as far as I understand, rules out any extrusion settings misconfiguration.

Also, I'd like to note that the hotbed is perfectly leveled, and the first layer is not too thin.

What could be causing this?

[image: 3D printed part over extrusion]

**My setup:**

- Printer: Creality CR-10S Pro
- Filament: eSun PLA
- Hotbed temp: 60 °C
- Hotend temp: 210 °C
- Infill: 20 %
- Layer height: 0.2 mm
- Nozzle Size: 0.4 mm
- Speed: 60 mm/s

Comment: It looks like your first few layers are ok, then you get a few layers with too much material.  It also looks like you may be getting some warping.

Comment: @PerryWebb you think so? PLA is not known to be prone to wrapping, and my room's temp is not too low.

Comment: It may just be the design, but the end on the bottom right looks turned up at the bottom.  It does look like the design has a rounded bottom.  Is the excess where the rounding stops.

Comment: I have had PLA warp.  What I did to prevent it is heat the bed to 75°C for the first layer, so that it sticks well, then change the bed temperature to 65°C afterwards to harden the PLA.

Comment: @PerryWebb Interesting. You're right about that corner, it did warp a bit. But there's over extrusion along the edge where it didn't warp. I was able to reduce the over extrusion a bit by slowing down the speed to 50 mm/s, and adjusting the z offset to be slightly higher.

Comment: I'm suspicious that overhand might be involved.

Comment: @YoavKadosh Have you found a solution? I have the same issue with my Ender 3

Comment: It's been a while but if I recall correctly, it was somewhat related to overhang (as @PerryWebb has suggested). The edges were rounded, so the lower layers had a shallow angle. Try to use a chamfer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your slicer, there might be settings that modify the flow ratio, First layer height or extrusion width for the first few layers. If those are different from the modifiers for the rest of the print you might be able to play around with these variables.